# Using LAG or Other function in SUM clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for some guidance on an Oracle SQL Query I have been struggling with.

I have a data table that contains Time Stamps and Help-Desk Ticket numbers...

Every time a technician makes a change to the ticket or logs a note the corresponding time stamp will log in the database along with the ticket number.  What i am trying to accomplish is to count the first occurrence of the ticket number in each series and i cant use distinct because it will not count the ticket again if the technician works the ticket again later in the day.  Please reference the attached picture.

http://s13.postimg.org/i5gx4l4nb/sample.jpg

Using the lag function i can flag the tickets at the row level but i cant add this to a SUM clause to accomplish my ultimate goal.

```
CASE WHEN LAG(IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.ENTITYID,1) over (ORDER BY IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.HISTORYDATE)=IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.ENTITYID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Any ideas or thoughts on what direction to take this in?

```
SELECT
  UPPER(IPCS_PLANNER.PLANNERSURNAME || ', ' || IPCS_PLANNER.PLANNERFIRSTNAME) AS FULL_NAME,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.ENTITYID) AS TICKETS_COUNT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LAG(IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.ENTITYID,1) over (ORDER BY IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.HISTORYDATE)=IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.ENTITYID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS TOUCH_COUNT
FROM 
  IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY,
  IPCS_PLANNER
WHERE
  IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.PLANNERID=IPCS_PLANNER.PLANNERID and
  TRUNC(IPCS_AUDIT_HISTORY.HISTORYDATE, 'IW')='30-DEC-13'
GROUP BY
  UPPER(IPCS_PLANNER.PLANNERSURNAME || ', ' || IPCS_PLANNER.PLANNERFIRSTNAME)
```

Comment: What is the desired output from the shown in the picture sample data?

Comment: A count of 5.  if i was to run the select on the table in the picture, i would get 4 for the ticket count and 5 for the touch count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:** Try it this way

```
SELECT full_name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT entityid) ticket_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT series) - COUNT(DISTINCT entityid) touch_count
  FROM
(
  SELECT plannerid, full_name, entityid, 
         rnum - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY plannerid, entityid ORDER BY rnum) series
    FROM
  (  
    SELECT p.plannerid, 
           UPPER(p.plannersurname || ', ' || p.plannerfirstname) full_name,
           h.historydate, 
           h.entityid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.plannerid ORDER BY h.historydate) rnum
      FROM ipcs_audit_history h JOIN ipcs_planner p
        ON h.plannerid = p.plannerid
     WHERE h.historydate >= TO_DATE('30-DEC-13')
       AND h.historydate <  TO_DATE('30-DEC-13') + 1
  ) q
) p
 GROUP BY plannerid, full_name
```

Sample output:

```
| FULL_NAME | TICKET_COUNT | TOUCH_COUNT |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|
| DOE, JOHN |            4 |           1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3ad6/6)** demo

Comment: Hello- thank you for taking time out of your day to work on this. I greatly appreciate your guidance.  Unfortunately i was not able to get your code to work but it did get me pointed in the right direction and i ultimately came up with the below statement that is working as desired.

Answer (score 5):

I could be misinterpreting your question, but I believe you just need to add `ROWS BETWEEN` to your `SUM()`:

```
SUM(ColName) OVER(ORDER BY Col2 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```