# Yii2 gridview running total for each SqlDataProvider row

Tags: gridview, yii2, rollup, subtotal, csqldataprovider

I have a `gridview` with an attribute `amount`. I would like to do a **running total** ( or subtotal / rollup ) of `amount` for each row. E.g.:

```
   amount  rollup
1.   2       2
2.   3       5
3.   2       7
4.   1       8
```

Is there a way to do this? Can you please point me to the right direction? I have no idea how to do this, and I don't find any relevant info, sorry.

**Ziki**: my `$dataProvider` is an `SqlDataProvider` so I can't use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399991/how-to-get-previous-and-next-row-model-id-in-yii2-gridview-data-row) solution. Can you maybe help me a little bit out how I can adjust it to an `SqlDataProvider`?

I'm referring to values like `$data["amount"]`. It seems I don't have any `key` or `index`, can it be? I'm getting:

> Undefined offset: 0 (or 1 or...)

It would be okay also if there was a SQL solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get previous and next row model ID in yii2 gridview data row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399991/how-to-get-previous-and-next-row-model-id-in-yii2-gridview-data-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [a simple SQL solution](http://www.wagonhq.com/blog/running-totals-sql) for that:

```
sum(amount) over (order by ... rows unbounded preceding)
```

The most important detail here is this: `rows unbounded preceding`

If you want the sum like this (so [slide one row below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010661/using-lag-or-other-function-in-sum-clause)):

```
   amount  rollup
1.   2       
2.   3       2
3.   2       5
4.   1       7
```

can be done with `window function`:

```
sum(amount) over (order by ... ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

Credits to @Hart CO